# Why does Visual Studio highlight double curly braces in Razor (.cshtml/.razor)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor, blazor

Although I have been working with Razor pages(`.cshtml`) and Razor components(`.razor`) in Blazor for a while in Visual Studio 2019, I did not stumble upon this feature up until now where it highlights anything between two pairs of braces: `{{ }}`.

It does it for both Razor pages(`.cshtml`) and Razor components(`.razor`). There is no mention of such syntax in the [Razor syntax documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0). What purpose was the `{{}}` syntax intended to serve? What am I missing?

This is what it looks like. The text is highlighted in hot pink:

| [image: The highlighted text between double braces.] |
| --- |

---

This is what the same highlight looks like in the light theme:

| [image: The highlighted text in light theme] |
| --- |

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mapped by the "HTML Client Template Value" setting in Tools|Options.

It is a piece of HTML syntax used in a.o. Angular for data-binding,
like `<h1> {{user.username}} </h1>`. Comparable to Blazor's yellow `@`

I don't think this has any meaning in a Blazor (razor) file. Safe to ignore.